# React route with exact path and param troubles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react `Route` path with params but it always matches even though I use `exact` on the `Route`.

```
    <Route exact path="/:term?" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/some" component={SomePage} />
```

If I nav to `/` then ok, no problem. If I nav to `/some` then I get both components rendered.

How do I prevent both components from being rendered for the second path?

A [Codebox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-surf-wnbgs)

EDIT: With `<Switch>` then the above example never routes to the `/some` path.

Comment: Are you also using `<Switch>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you have wrapped your `Route` components in a `Switch` component, so that only one of the routes gets used.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: Answered from my phone so apologies don't have access to update the codesandbox

Comment: Well, it seems better, but it's still not working.When I use `<Switch>` then it always matches the first `<Route>` and never gets to the second `<Route>`.

Comment: That's how <Switch> works, it renders first matching path. Just place `some` path before `:term?` inside switch.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is /some, then  and  will all render because they all match the path. We want to pick only one  to render. If we’re at /some we don’t want to also match /:term?. Here’s how to do it with [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch):

```js
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/some" component={SomePage} />
    <Route exact path="/:term?" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be on `/home`. I just moved it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/some" component={SomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/:term?" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```